# Lync 2010 RTM - IM Takes Exactly 10 Minutes to Appear from an External Domain

Tags: lync, lync-2010

The customer I'm currently working with has a Lync 2010 RTM environment and IM's from external domains fail (according to the sender as a failed message appears) however the IM is actually received EXACTLY 10 minutes later. Sometimes sending IMs externally works, but more often does not. Sending IMs internally there are no issues. I can initiate Lync video conferences with an external domain however they randomly end. The Free/Busy information works fine and an external domain can see my status change instantly.

I've checked the DNS SRV records for Dymantec Federation and they are present, port 5061 is open and the SIP address is present in the SAN certificate. I haven't confirmed whether the Dynamic Federation configuration is correct yet. I'm going to enable Message Queueing Routing feature on the Edge server Monday.

My initial questions are:

1. Has anyone come across this issue before?
2. Is this fixed in an CU release?
3. What further troubleshooting can I complete?

I can provide the logs from Snooper if that helps? I've noticed that the session from the external domain is received almost instantly in the Snooper log however it's another 10 minutes in the log analysis until there seems to be another session which is when the IM is actually displayed in my IM window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of your specific issue, but running the RTM release of a 5-years old software which received plenty of updates after being released is just crazy.

Your issue could very well be caused by a bug that has long been fixed... but there are also *lots* of bugs and issues which have been fixed by CUs, not to mention new features which have been introduced.

My ***strong*** suggestion is to apply the latest available CU for Lync 2010; *then*, if you still have issues, go investigating them.